# How to get the ADO.NET entityframework templates in VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c#-4.0

could any one help me in order to get the Entity Framework in VS 2008?Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework templates are part of the VS 2008, so these should be installed by default. Did you intended to ask, how to use them ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install VS2008 SP1 as EF did not appear until .NET Framework 3.5 SP1. A vanilla install of VS2008 will not include EF.

Comment: BTW you don't get C#4 until VS2010